# Как сделать всплывающую форму на сайте?

Tags: html, css, javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать всплывающую форму как, например, на этом сайте http://www.apus-advert.ru/
при нажатии вверху справа на кнопку "обратный звонок"?
Благодарю!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитайте [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/249912/javascript-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B8/)

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/SbxHT/

Comment: Олег, супер пример, спасибо! изучу
но все таки меня немного не то интересовало. в приведенном примере затемняется фон и табличка выскакивает посередине. вне зависимости от того, где кнопка

Answer (score 0):

Это называется Modal Window и на сайте она сделано с помощью framework'а Twitter Bootstrap.
Процесс создания хорошо описан в [документации](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

Comment: Genson, я в web-пограммировании пока профан, так что вопрос: я так понял это нужно подключать какую то стороннюю библиотеку? как ее подключать что то не понял и ответ не нашел. подскажите, правильно ли я понял и как подключить библиотеку. блаогдарю!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте модальное окно от JQuery UI, на [сайте](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal) всё очень хорошо показано и рассказано.